# Yahoo Oauth2 step 3

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, yahoo

I am trying to create a quick web app that authenticates into a users Yahoo account, but I am having trouble getting 'user approval'.

[Yahoo Auth Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gFvN.png)

Personally, every time I go to external website and have to authenticate, I usually log into my account.  This seems to be redirecting me to a page and asking for a code. I have 0 idea what code I would need to supply in order to authenticate.  And if I dont know, my users certainly wont! I am building a flask app, and I have tried to model my code around [this repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-oauth-example).

I have added some code specifically for Yahoo, but cant seem to connect the dots. New YahooSignIn subclass in the oauth.py file below:

```
class YahooSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
def __init__(self):
    super(YahooSignIn, self).__init__('yahoo')
    self.service = OAuth2Service(
        name='yahoo',
        consumer_id=self.consumer_id,
        consumer_secret=self.consume_secret,
        authorize_url='https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth',
        access_token_url='https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token',
        base_url='http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/'
    )

def authorize(self):
    return redirect(self.service.get_authorize_url(
        scope='email',
        response_type='code',
        redirect_uri=self.get_callback_url())
    )

def callback(self):
    def decode_json(payload):
        return json.loads(payload.decode('utf-8'))

    if 'code' not in request.args:
        return None, None, None
    oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
        data={'code': request.args['code'],
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
              'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()},
        decoder=decode_json
    )
    me = oauth_session.get('me?fields=id,email').json()
    return (
        'yahoo$' + me['id'],
        me.get('email').split('@')[0],
        me.get('email')
    )
```

The only other change made was to the index.html page to add an additional link with a 'yahoo' parameter

```
<p><a href="{{ url_for('oauth_authorize', provider='yahoo') }}">Login with Yahoo</a></p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this one has stumped me the last two nights and I would love to move past this!

Answer (score 0):

Previous to this year (2018/19) I had been using Yahoo's Oauth 1.0 API. This year I ran into problems using it so I switched to using Oauth 2.0 via the yahoo-oauth library linked below. They have a nice page that describes how to use their library. Here is the code that I used.

```
from yahoo_oauth import OAuth2

class YahooFantasyAPI:

  def fetchGameID(self):
    session = self.getSession()
    r = session.get(
    'https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/nfl'
    )
    print(r.text)

  def getSession(self):
    oauth = OAuth2(None, None, from_file='oauth2.json')

    if not oauth.token_is_valid():
        oauth.refresh_access_token()

    return oauth.session

api = YahooFantasyAPI()
fetchGameID()
```

https://yahoo-oauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/